# Can we really understand $R$ by studying $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

According to [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf), the category $R\operatorname{-Mod}$ reveals a lot about $R$. However after completing the first eight chapters, I still found no examples where this happens.

Can someone give some honest examples where the category of modules do tell us a lot about the underlying ring? Better still, such kind of information is very difficult if one looks at the ring directly.

Thanks very much!

Comment: See here for my perspective: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124077/what-does-r-mathrmmod-tell-us-about-r/124086#124086

Comment: @AlexYoucis Quite informative. But I am a little bit suspicious about the power of Yoneda's. It is often argued that with Yoneda, we can study $X$ in a category $\operatorname{C}$ by looking at $\operatorname{Hom}(A,X)$ for all $A$. But I feel this is not quite the case. Since in Yoneda embedding $\operatorname{C}\to\operatorname{Set}^{C}$, the morphisms in the latter category are natural transformations. So we are looking at $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,X)$ not only as sets, but they contain information about how $A$ interact with $B$ for all $A,B$ that interact with $X$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5243

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the study of structure of rings using internal structure such as ideals vs. external structure such as general modules over the ring, you might find of interest the following nice introduction in J.P. Lafon: *Ideals and Modules*, in Hazewinkel (ed.), *Handbook of Algebra,* vol.1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The ring R may be considered as a right or left R module over itself and various module theorems may be used. However if you wish to apply various radicals such as the Jacobson radical or prime radical you need to use ring theory.